# IndexError: list index out of range - Error generado por la variable con Glob.glob[0]

Tags: python, csv

Primeramente buenas a todos!,

Les explico, el programa tiene que copiar un archivo de formato "csv" de nombre incompleto (ej: temp*, uso el * para completar) a otra carpeta.

El mismo código que uso me funciona para algunos "csv" pero en otros me arroja el mismo error ("IndexError: list index out of range").

Codigo INPUT:

```
##Librerias
import glob
import shutil
### Archivo a elegir
csv = glob.glob("temp*")[0]
#Rutas de Origen y destino
RUTAAPLORIGEN= C:/Temp/
RUTAAPLDESTINO= D:/Datos/Temporales

##Copia los archivos
shutil.copy(RUTAAPLORIGEN, RUTAAPLDESTINO)
```

Codigo OUTPUT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Temp\MoverArchivo.py", line 221, in <module>
    csv = glob.glob("temp*")[0]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Lo unico que puedo decir, es que el error se debe a que glob.glob te está devolviendo una lista vacía (en este caso, eso significa que no encuentra ningún archivo que empiece con temp).  Podrías ver el directorio de trabajo con print(os.getcwd()) o print(pathlib.Path.cwd()) y así saber en que directorio está buscando los csv. Luego, con eso podrás verificar que los csvs estén buscandose en el directorio correcto. Si el directorio es correcto, entonces, te podré ayudar mejor si editas la pregunta y agregas los nombres con los que suelen aparecer los archivos.

Comment: Añadiendo a lo que ha dicho @DanteS., si únicamente vas a trabajar con csv-s, tal y como dices en el enunciado, entonces te recomiendo cambiar el patrón a "temp*.csv", para evitar problemas.